# UIWebView created through IB and through code not orientation friendly

Tags: ios, uiwebview, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait

I am writing this in viewDidLoad,

```
// Programmatically creating uiwebview. 
UIWebView *webVPrg = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:webVPrg];
[webVPrg loadRequest:urlReq];
```

The web view created here does not align itself to portrait and landscape orientations properly, whereas if the web view is **created through Interface Builder**, it works fine.

(Not sure if something wrong with **initWithFrame:self.view.frame**)

What could be the problem?

Comment: LOL for the down vote. There are worse questions than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `autoresizingMask`:

```
webVPrg.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

to make the view automatically adapt its size according to its superview's. You will possibly need to do the same with your `self.view` as well.

Comment: right, sometimes just asking a question leads you to seeing the answer. :-)

Comment: Hang on. I think the autoresizingmask should be applied to the web view. This doesn't work exactly.

Comment: yeah, I did copy/paste from a source file of mine and immediately after that I realized your web view was called differently...